# How do I search photos by player ID?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

Online profile pages in New Pokémon Snap list an ID under the player’s name. Can I search for a player’s photos if I know their player ID?

[image: My player ID]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, while you can view another user's player ID on their profile page, there doesn't seem to be any way to search by player ID.